# Bootstrap carousel double slide glitch on iPhone devices

Tags: iphone, safari, carousel

Just want to ask if anyone knows how to fix a bootstrap carousel glitch on iPhone devices, it autoplays but the slide is glitchy or something, it double slides per item. Only at iPhone X-11 / safari browsers. Works fine on chrome and desktops. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am experiencing this same issue, please contact me if you have found a resolution

Answer (score 0):

fixed the blinking (but the slide animation from right to left will not work - slides just appear):

```
.carousel-item {
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0); -moz-transform: translateZ(0); 
}
```

related to: [Bootstrap 4 Carousel is blinking during transitions on safari browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53640528/bootstrap-4-carousel-is-blinking-during-transitions-on-safari-browser/64092795#64092795)